# specs2 test does not fail

Tags: scala, specs2

Considering the following

```
package stopwatch
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class StopWatchSpecs extends Specification {

  "This spec" should {

    "fail here" in {
      2 + 2 === 5
    }

  }

}
```

This test always succeeds (but it shouldn't) if i use the latest version of specs2 framework (3.8.5) as suggested by the quick start guide [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/website/SPECS2-3.8.5/quickstart.html)

However it does fail (correctly) if i use an older version (2.5), does anyone have experienced the same behaviour?

Comment: I just tested with 3.8.6 and it fails as expected with both sbt and intellij.

Comment: Yep I can confirm it works with 3.8.6, solved.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in `specs2-core-3.8.6`.

Comment: Thanks for the promptly reply, however i don't understand why my question has been downvoted, it is a problem and this question/thread could be helpful for other people too.

Comment: I've set it back to 0 :-).